# A question regarding the status of CH in the Gitik model

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing, large-cardinals

Consider models of ZF+"Every uncountable cardinal is singular" (eg. Moti Gitik: "All uncountable cardinals can be singular", Israel journal of Mathematics, 35(1-2): 61-88, 1980).  How should CH be formulated in such models?  Can CH be false in such models and if so, how many intermediate cardinalities between $\omega$ and $2^{\omega}$ can there possibly be since such models are choiceless? I apologize in advance for the ignorance of the question--it is asked honestly. (As regards how CH should be formulated in such models I may have  answered my own question if in fact such models are indeed choiceless).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is a long comment at the moment.)

To my best of knowledge pretty much all these questions are somewhat open.

By somewhat I mean that we don't quite know the answer <del>for Gitik's model, or</del> for "most models", or many limitations on what can happen.

We do know that it is consistent that $\omega_1$ is singular and $\sf CH$ holds in the sense that there are no intermediate cardinalities between $\omega$ and the continuum (e.g. in Truss' model, where the perfect set property holds). But it can be that the continuum itself is the countable union of countable sets and the continuum hypothesis fails in the sense that there are intermediate cardinals (as shown by Miller to be true in the Feferman-Levy mode). It should be noted that if the continuum is the countable union of countable sets, then $\omega_1$ is singular.

To my knowledge, <del>it's not even clear whether the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets in Gitik's original model,</del> (see the remarks below) and finding how many cardinalities are between cardinals is often a daunting task.

Here is [a related MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86621/the-continuum-hypothesis-and-countable-unions).

---

Some additional remarks.

1. Gitik actually proves in his paper (the last theorem) that the continuum is not a countable union of countable sets. He also proves that every set is the countable union of smaller sets. In particular the continuum is the countable union of sets which have cardinality smaller than the continuum, but are uncountable. Therefore the continuum hypothesis is false in Gitik's model.

   On the other hand, this does not tell us how many intermediate cardinals are there. It might be just one, or it might be many. This fact does not appear in the original paper, and I don't think it has a definitive answer elsewhere in the literature.
2. Miller proves in his paper about long Borel hierarchies (the online version, in the appendix) that if one modifies the collapse of $\aleph_\omega$ then one gets a model which is "similar to Gitik's".

   - This seems closer to what Truss did in his model, where the continuum hypothesis does in fact hold. But not quite.
   - <del>It's still unclear whether or in this model, or in Gitik's, the continuum hypothesis does hold.</del>

Comment: Has much detailed research been done on Gitik's original model? By the way, your answer has been helpful, thanks.

Comment: I don't know exactly. I think that the majority of work was to try and generalize or mimic his result, rather than investigating a particular model.

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that 0-sharp exists in the Gitik model? I just copied Gitic's paper and am reading through it now.  I have further questions about it that I may ask as proper mathstackexchange questions.

Comment: Thomas, it's a theorem of Magidor that if both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are singular (and therefore necessarily have countable cofinality) then $0^\#$ exists. It is also a more recent theorem, of Ralf Schindler I believe, that in that case not only $0^\#$ exists, but there is an inner model with a Woodin cardinal. That theorem was extended and with his student Busche they have shown that if all limit ordinals have countable cofinality then determinacy holds in $L(\Bbb R)$. All these are much stronger than just the existence of $0^\#$.

Comment: @Thomas: Last night I gave a closer inspection to Gitik's paper, and I noticed that he actually proves that the continuum hypothesis is false in that model.

Comment: :On what page does this proof begin?  Also on page 62 in his "brief outline" he states that "In the universe V[G] thus obtained all regular cardinals of V, and hence all cardinals, become ordinals of cofinality $\omega$.  V[G] satisfies all the axioms of ZFC except for the power set axiom."  This seems odd seeing that it is stated that in the Gitik model $'mathsf{AC}_\omega$ and DC are said to fail.  Also, Gitik shows that Replacement holds in V[G].  I wonder what would happen if one 'replaced' Replacement with  Collection and Choice by the well-ordering principle as suggested in the Gitman,

Comment: @Thomas: This is an immediate consequence of Theorem 6.5 (the last theorem of the paper).

Comment: Hamkins, and Johnstone paper "What is the theory ZFC without Power Set?"?  Under these assumptions, would Gitik be able to still obtain his results?

Comment: @Tomach Benyamean: I have no idea what you mean in that last sentence of your comment. It feels to me that you have very weak grasp of actual set theory, and you're just asking questions that "sound interesting". I've been there myself, so I can't condemn anyone doing that, but just asking arbitrary questions makes no sense. You need to understand the set theory behind the proofs and the axioms, and then you can formulate reasonable questions in a non-arbitrary fashion.

Comment: As for my last question and remarks in the "comments", they may be ignorant, but they are honest.  I was just wondering...  Also, in his paper, the "Gitik Model" must be the symmetric model $N_G$ constructed inside V[G].  This is correct?

Comment: Yes, but it's more complicated than that. He uses class forcing to construct a model where $\sf ZFC$ fails, more specifically the power set axiom fails (this models becomes somewhat similar to $H(\omega_1)$ the hereditarily countable sets). Then he uses symmetry arguments to define a class of that model, where the axioms of $\sf ZF$ do hold. This is quite pushing the term "symmetric model", as it differs from the usual case of set forcing, and defining the class in a model of $\sf ZFC$, or even class forcing which preserves the axioms of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: So did Gitik purposely use class forcing to construct a model where ZFC fails, specifically where the power set axiom fails?  Why? Isn't the purpose of any type of forcing (including class forcing) to construct extensions of ZFC (or more generally the theory T in question) and if you construct an extension where an axiom of T fails, say, you basically screwed up the construction of the forcing extension? (I hope this isn't a stupid question....)

Comment: Forcing, set forcing, *always* preserves all the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, which is why we need symmetric models to contradict $\sf AC$. However one can prove that if $V$ is a model of $\sf ZF$ where all the limit ordinals have countable cofinality, then there is no model $V\subseteq M$ of $\sf ZFC$ with the same ordinals. Since forcing does not add ordinals, if we want to do the Gitik construction with forcing, we need to violate $\sf ZFC$ somehow before defining the symmetric model. [...]

Comment: [...] So in Gitik's work the symmetric extension is careful enough so it restores the power set axiom. In one of my current projects the situation is similar. We end up blowing the continuum to a proper class, but using a careful argument we show that we can find a model of $\sf ZF$ to our liking within that universe. Note that this can only happen with class forcing, since class forcing can easily screw up the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, with plenty of examples (see Sy Friedman's writing on the topic).

Comment: A question:  Although in your revised answer you state that, in Gitik's paper, Theorem 6.5 "does not tell us how many intermediate cardinals there are....", doesn't the proof of 6.5(2), that is, $N_G \models \operatorname{grad}(2^{\aleph_0})=2$ give us a clue as to how many intermediate cardinal there are since it seemingly gives us a value for $2^{\aleph_0}$ in $N_G$?

Comment: No, because it doesn't give us a concrete value. Had the value been $\aleph_5$ we could have known exactly how many intermediate cardinals are there. But in this case it might be that there are only finitely many, or that there are continuum many, or maybe more. Suppose that $2^\omega=\bigcup B_n$ where every $B_n$ is uncountable (but the countable union of countable sets). It might be the case that almost all the $B_n$'s have the same size, and it might be that not; it might be that partial infinite unions give different cardinals; or that we can find a whole other sequence of such $B_n$'s.