# First Uncountable Ordinal Cofinality: Needs AC?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

Say $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal. The reason I care about $\omega_1$ is

1. Any countable subset of $\omega_1$ is bounded (or if you prefer, there is no countable cofinal subset).

This is obvious because

2. A countable union of countable sets is countable.

Now, I'm told that we cannot prove (2) without at least some weak version of AC. Question: Does (1) also require AC?

Seems possible that some ordinalistic magic lets us be explicit about the relevant sequence of bijections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it requires the axiom of choice.

It was shown by Feferman and Levy, as one of the first uses of forcing, that it is consistent that $\omega_1$ is the countable union of countable sets. This means that there is a countable subset of $\omega_1$ which is unbounded. This is just assuming the consistency of $\sf ZFC$. (The idea is simple, for each $n$ add many bijections between $\omega$ and $\omega_n$; if you are careful enough, you can ensure that these are all the new bijections you add, and therefore there is no bijection between $\omega$ and the "original" $\omega_\omega$, which makes it the least uncountable ordinal of the model.)

This result was later generalized by Gitik who showed that assuming additional axioms are consistent, we can construct a model where ***every*** limit ordinal is the countable union of smaller ordinals. It was shown that at least some additional axioms are needed for such a result, although it seems that Gitik's original assumptions are probably stronger than needed.

Comment: Gitik's paper is behind a paywall, but a review is http://www.jstor.org/stable/2274202?loginSuccess=true&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents. See also Asaf's answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775565/a-question-regarding-the-status-of-ch-in-the-gitik-model for cool things about the model.

Comment: Thanks Noah! There is more to say about models where $\omega_1$ is singular. But unfortunately I think there's more interesting questions that haven't been answered, and they seem to be incredibly hard.

Comment: Thanks. Not complaining, just curious: My labels (i) and (ii) were edited to 1. and 2. Why is that better?

Comment: @David: The `1.` is part of the standard markup, so it creates an actual list in terms of HTML elements, which looks better due to proper indentation.

Comment: Just now discovered the notion of "accepting" an answer, if the delay seems curious...

Comment: @David: It's fine, I've had delays of three years, slightly over a week is nothing! :-)